# Javascript refresh page automatically

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page. Everytime I add new content to the page, the user needs to refresh the page in order to see the new content.

What I want to do is to refresh the page automatically for them regardless of browser.

I tried putting the following but the screen flickers so many times that it does not prove to be useful:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       location.reload();

    </script>
```

Comment: This script will refresh the page every time it's loaded, and it loads every time it refreshes. You should not be doing this. Could you describe your needs in more detail?

Comment: Reloading a page is expensive and slow. Would you rather just have certain elements in the page update without having to refresh the whole page? If so, check into AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript you show there does indeed reload the page.  Every single time the page loads, as soon as it reaches that JavaScript.  The flickering you're seeing is probably the fact that it in an infinite cycle of reloading.  What you need to do is perform an AJAX request to the server to find out if there is new content, and *then* reload the page if there is.  Or, alternatively, use the AJAX to actually update the new content on the page.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I researched further and wouldn't the following code also fix the issue: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">